# I am trying to read mp3 file tags in a drectory and move them to a new directory sorted by artist and artist's albums using Python

Tags: python

This code....

```
 import os

 import shutil
 from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

 # Set the source and destination directories
 source_dir = "E:\Radio Metaverse\Songs\Greatest Hits"
 destination_dir = "/sorted"
 # Walk through the directory tree and find all mp3 files
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
  for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        # Use Mutagen to extract the artist and album tags
        mp3_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        tags = EasyID3(mp3_path)
        artist = tags.get("artist", ["Unknown Artist"])[0]
        album = tags.get("album", ["Unknown Album"])[0]

        # Create directories for the artist and album if they don't exist
        artist_dir = os.path.join(destination_dir, artist)
        if not os.path.exists(artist_dir):
            os.makedirs(artist_dir)
        album_dir = os.path.join(artist_dir, album)
        if not os.path.exists(album_dir):
            os.makedirs(album_dir)

        # Move the mp3 file to the album directory
        destination_path = os.path.join(album_dir, file)
        shutil.move(mp3_path, destination_path)

 print("Done!")
```

But it produces this error...

```
OSError: ;WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorect: 
sorted/Joe Walsh\\Confessions.

'OSError:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Any help wold be greatly apprecited.. Trust me I have been trying to solve this off and on for days.

I tried many things that I got from Googling but nothing helped.  I even tried putin r before the paths as in    destination_dir = r'/sorted'

Comment: If you use backslashes in a path, you need to escape them, e.g. `"E:\\Radio Metaverse\\..."`

Comment: Also, `"/sorted"` means an absolute path, but such a path would not exist on windows. Perhaps you meant relative to the current dir? In that case, it would just be `"sorted"`

Comment: (If you're making this to sort/manage your music collection, you should check out MusicBrainz Picard which is open source and, coincidentally, written in Python.)

Comment: First, thank you both for your help!  It turned out that the program works to some degree after I made the suggested changes but it hangs up on some artists.  So I am going to just use Picard.  I just wanted a simple script that would do this but no going to beat my head against the wall as I do not have the knowledge or skills at this point in time.  thanks once again